# When are Crashlytics custom logs sent?

Tags: android, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I have a BaseActivity that I use as a parent for all my Activities. I'd like to log Activity events (onCreate(), onStart(), onResume(), etc.) to Crashlytics, so when a crash happens, I know what the user was doing and what Activities were currently alive. I added the following code to all the methods that I want to log:

```
CrashlyticsCore.getInstance().log(getClass().getSimpleName() + ".onResume()");
```

I'm wondering if it's a good idea to do it. Are the logs only sent when a crash happens? Will I not spam the server and produce unnecessary network calls for the users? Perhaps there's a better method of implementing bread crumbs with Crashlytics?

Comment: Just initialze crashlytics at your first activity's oncreate or your application's oncreate. U dont need to add custom logs in this case, whenever your app crashes, crashlytics automatically sends data.
https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install

Comment: But it only sends the stack trace and I want to be able to reproduce the crash by going through the same screens as the user did. Sometimes the stack trace is not enough to reproduce a bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the name subtly suggests, Crashlytics will only trigger a report (and send a log) after a crash, and will only contain up to 64kb of log history as stated in the [docs](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/enhanced-reports.html): "To make sure that sending crash reports has the smallest impact on your user’s devices, Crashlytics logs have a maximum size of 64 KB. When a log exceeds 64 KB, the earliest logged values will be dropped in order to maintain this threshold."

If you ask my personal opinion, it's not good practice or useful to log every `onCreate`, `onResume`. A Crashlytics report will already contain the stacktrace giving you insight on the error.

If you have caught exceptions and want to log those, you can do so as explain [here](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/caught-exceptions.html), by calling `Crashlytics.logException(e);`. Again only 8 of these will be stored: "For any individual app session, only the most recent 8 logged exceptions are stored".

Comment: Thank you for a great answer.
I want to explain why I need onCreate, onResume, etc. Sometimes a stack trace is not enough to reproduce a bug. I'd like to know what exact screens the user went through and if they were rotating the device. Crashlytics doesn't provide me with those details, does it? I heard that Firebase is better when it comes to this feature, but I can't replace Crashlytics in my project right now.

Comment: Well Crashlytics already tells you a few of these, any crash report will contain the orientation of the device (and free memory, free disk space, android version, whether the app is in focus...). I havent used Firebase so i cannot comment on it. You can just use log every `onCreate`, etc. As I said, you'll only be able to see a stack of 64kb. I'm not sure how many logs that comes out to be, just gotta try and learn I guess. But perhaps it's better to log other places of importance, I know that comes out vague, but you as the app developer will know best what points in code is best to log.

Comment: I sent an email with the same question to Fabric support. They answered: "Great idea! Logs are only sent along with a crash, so you should be all set :)"